# Getting thumbnails from android gallery - sdcard

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I have the absoluite path of an image file name in sdcard. Is there a way to get the thumbnail of it just like the way they show in android gallery? The reason i need is I have few images selected from the android gallery and http post it to a server. If the size of the file is huge, it takes a long time to upload because of slow mobile data. Instead of the file, if i can get the thumbnail of it, it will be easy to upload. 
I can work on image resize to resize the image on my own before uploading it. But I would like to explore if there is a easier way?